# Click event - get the target where the mousedown started instead of the mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouse

In a click event (attached to document) I want to figure out the target when the user *started pressing* the mousebutton.

Example:

- User presses mousebutton on a *custom* popup
- User moves the mouse outside the popup and let go

In that case the code below will return a `target` outside the popup, but I want to figure out if it *started* within the popup.

```
$(document).click(function(e)
{
    // will return the target during *releasing the mouse button*
    // but how to get the target where the *mouse press started*
    console.log(e.target); 
}
```

Of course  I could track this manually by listening to mousedown and saving this within a variable - but I rather have something *native*, because:

- less code
- I might be missing edge cases

Both Jquery or vanilla JavaScript answers are good to me (but preference vanilla)

Comment: perhaps use the `mouseup` event if you don't mind it being fired earlier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use mousedown together with a mouseup function, and have them both saving their targets to a global variable, then compare them in an if statement.

```
let downTarget, upTarget;

$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    downTarget = e.target;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    upTarget = e.target;
});

if(upTarget === downTarget){ 
    *do stuff*
};
```

Comment: didn't find any native solution, so accepted this one. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a very expensive solution, does the `clickEvent` not store the `mousedown` element?

Answer (score 0):

just use the event `mousedown` instead click like

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e)
{
    console.log(e.target); 
}
```

also has another event that verifies if the mouse is over that is the `mouseover`